# Change file structure using Visual Studio to the common one used by GitHub projects (both solution and project in src folder)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

A common structure seen on most projects on GitHub is the following. A good example is [Json.Net repository](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/). I want to achieve the same thing using Visual Studio 2019:

```
MyProject
├── Doc
│   ├── txt/md/... files
├── Src
│   ├── .sln
│        ├── Project1 (eg. netstandard lib)
│        └── Project2 (eg. tests)
├── .gitignore
├── LICENSE.md
└── Readme.md
```

Similar questions on SO ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43058994/how-to-add-src-folder-at-solution-root), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267200/visual-studio-solutions-folder-as-real-folders)) move the "projects" into a folder not the "solution". **Note that in this structure, the solution is *also* inside the "Src" folder.**

I've adapted some of the [suggestions such as switching to folder view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48302336/10401748) and that way I successfully move the entire .sln and project folders into 'src' folder but the problem is that Visual Studio creates a new solution at root. And the final structure becomes this:

```
MyProject
├── Doc
│   ├── txt/md/... files
├── Src
│   ├── .sln 
│        ├── Project1 (eg. netstandard lib)
│        └── Project2 (eg. tests)
├── .gitignore
├── LICENSE.md
├── Readme.md
└── Extra_solution.sln <-- this is the problem
```

The red circled solution in below screenshot was created as soon as I opened the moved solution:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

So the structure you want is common, as outlined by David Fowler here:  https://gist.github.com/davidfowl/ed7564297c61fe9ab814.  Note that the `.sln` file is at the root, and I find this to be far more common.

What I do when creating it in Visual Studio is unload the project (via a right-click on the project), then move it, then re-add the project to the solution.

There's another way, and that is to do everything via the command line:

```
mkdir MyProject
cd MyProject
dotnet new sln
dotnet new classlib -o src/Project1
dotnet new mstest -o src/Project2
dotnet sln add src/Project1
dotnet sln add src/Project2
```